# Handling exception while using data adapter on SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-express

I am getting this error message

> Cannot open database "stock" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'user-pc\computer'.

Code I have written:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=user-pc\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=stock; Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"))
    {
        using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("Select username,password from userprofile where username=@username",con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserName.Text);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            string userid = dt.Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
```

It shows error on `da.fill(dt)`

Comment: Could be a whole raft of things that. Can you connect to that instance on that machine as that user outside of code. With Sql Server Management studio for instance? If so can you see the database?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson yes i can connect via sql server management studio 2008-R2

Comment: @user1700961 When you connect to SSMS, you're connecting to `user-pc\SQLEXPRESS` correct?

Comment: Not waht I said. To that instance on that machine as the same windows user that's running your application. This could be permissions to the db, connectivity to the instance, the machine. Even in certain scenarios, a DNS issue. In general this is a doh moment, but you have to stop making the this should work assumption and find out waht does from where.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you can connect via Server Management and since you tagged the question `asp.net`, my guess the problem lies with using `Integrated Security=True` in your connection string.

The application you're developing and starting up is probably using different credentials, and as such cannot log into the database.

Here are a few suggestions:

- Just to make sure try the Server Browser available in Visual Studio, and see if you can connect to the database. If you can, use the connection string (be weary of the integrated security, as I mentioned earlier!) used by Server Browser.
- Try turning on the SQL Browser Windows service.
- Check if the SQL named pipe is enabled (should be by default, but just to be sure).
- Create a console application and copy your code - console applications will use your credentials, so even integrated security should work.